# How to store the order of added inputs in php?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a form:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button type="button" onClick="addFile()">Add file</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="addText()">Add text</button>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I add inputs to the form by javascript:

```
var form;
window.onload=function(){
    form=document.getElementById("myForm");
    }
function addFile(){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="file";
    input.name="files[]";
    form.appendChild(input);
    }
function addText(){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="text";
    input.name="texts[]";
    form.appendChild(input);
    }
```

I'd like to store the order in which the inputs were added. so in php i could do something like this:

```
foreach($_POST["texts"] as $text){
    $db -> insert("table", $text, $index);
    }
foreach($_POST["file_paths"] as $path){
    $db -> insert("table", $path, $index);
    }
```

So in the database I could have something like this:

0 "text1"
1 "data/uploads/image.jpg"
2 "text2"

I tried adding all the contents to an array in $_POST, then array_search() to get the index, but it's not going to work when two input's content is the same, and it seems sloppy.

So how would you go about with such a task?

Comment: Have you examined the actual HTTP transactions?

Comment: no. Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: What is `$index` supposed to be? You don't define it!

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input everytime you add an input to your form and give it the value of a variable that you will increment with each addition:

```
var index = 0;

function addHidden(){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="hidden";
    input.value=index;
    input.name="hidden" + (index++);
    form.appendChild(input);
}
```

In **PHP** side:

```
var $index = 0;

foreach($_POST["texts"] as $text){
    $db -> insert("table", $text, $_POST["hidden" + ($index++)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not sure I understand the question.  By default they will have an order they are added in.  It's no issue to get the correct index in a loop.

```
foreach($_POST["texts"] as $index => $text){
    $db -> insert("table", $text, $index)
}
```

Why can't you simply do the index like this

Your data will be like this by default

```
array(
    0 => 'some_text',
    1 => 'some_text',
    2 => 'some_other_text',
    3 => 'some_text'
```

Your loop will generate this

```
 $index = 0;
 $text = 'some_text';
 //-----------------
 $index = 1;
 $text = 'some_text';
 //-----------------
 $index = 2;
 $text = 'some_other_text';
 //-----------------
 $index = 3;
 $text = 'some_text';
 //-----------------
```

Maybe I'm missing something but seems pretty straight forward to use the numbered index in the foreach loop.

**UPDATE** after talking in the comments I would do something like this ( have not tested this code )

Javascript:

```
var index = 0;

function addFile(){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="file";
    input.name="inp_file_" + index;
    form.appendChild(input);
    ++index;
}

function addText(){
    var input=document.createElement("input");
    input.type="text";
    input.name="inp_text_" + index;
    form.appendChild(input);
    ++index;
}
```

In PHP side:

```
//merge $_POST and $_FILES ~ 
//I don't feel like sorting that out as it should be easy to do for you, also you may 
//be doing other things with the $_FILES array, but what you want is something like this 
// for the input array.
// one last note as I saw you said you tried merging the $_FILES into the $_POST array, it's generally a bad practice to modify the $_POST array, and is better to create a new array with the data you want.
$input = array( 
    'inp_text_0' => 'some_text',
    'inp_text_2' => 'some_other_text',
    'inp_file_1' => 'filepath.txt'
);

foreach ($input as $key => $value ){
    if( preg_match('/^inp_(?P<type>text|file)_(?P<index>[0-9]+)$/', $key, $match) ){
        $db -> insert("table", $value, $match['index'], $match['type']);    
    }
}
```

For the Regx  `(?P<name> .. )` is a named capture group, it's not necessary but it helps make the example clear.  Basically you are creating a list of inputs who's name will match this pattern.

- `^` - start of string
- `inp_` - match the text "inp_" literally
- `(?P<type>text|file)` - named capture as type of either "text" or "file"
- `_` - match the text "_" literally ~ added just for clarity ie. it looks nicer
- `(?P<index>[0-9]+)` - named capture as index of one or more numbers from 0 to 9
- `$` match end of string

Regx Demo https://regex101.com/r/nZ7iO5/1

Comment: It would work with the text inputs, but would not work with the files. All the file's paths are passed to this script, they are in a different array, and their indexes would not be in the correct order

Comment: What do you mean not in the correct order, they would be in the order they are created.

Comment: if i have 2 arrays passed, one is $texts[] the other is $files[].
looping trough $texts[] would insert:
0 "text1"
1 "text2", etc..
looping trough $files[] would insert:
0 "files1"
1 "files2", etc..
this way I could have multiple contents with the same index

Comment: ? what do you mean, does the data get stored in the same table?

Comment: yes, and  it's important to get the order later on, inserting them into separate tables would not solve anything, since i could still not decide for example that after file1 comes text3

Comment: Yes but when they are in the same table how do you know what is a file and what is text, what if I enter in file.csv as my text.  You can add another field that is hidden such as others have indicated.

Comment: There is an other field in the db called type, I can insert into that field dynamically without a problem, so I did not mention it.

Comment: So you are adding both file and text into the same database table?

Comment: @Eduárdó - I updated my answer, but by you leaving the type out, I hadn't considered using a regular expression. This way it also solves the what type is it issue as well and you only need one set of code to do the insert into the database instead of needless duplication of that, and the crutch of using another field to track the index, also needless markup.  So even if that 'part works' it can still be valuable to explain the whole process to get a better fit for the answer.